# Swift fetch from React Native asyncstorage

Tags: swift, react-native, asyncstorage

I'm trying to fetch values that are stored in React Natives [AsyncStorage](https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage) with Swift. There isn't a lot of documentation around and most of the information about how to do this is outdated. How can I go about fetching data from [AsyncStorage](https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage) in swift?

```
let storage = RCTBridge.module(forClass: RNCAsyncStorage.self)
storage.multiGet(["count"])
```

I'm getting this error from the above line of code. `Cannot find 'RNCAsyncStorage' in scope`

Comment: I don't know how to fetch using AsyncStorage, but I do know this works and does what you want: https://github.com/KjellConnelly/react-native-shared-group-preferences#readme

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? im trying to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Nope, no solution yet. Please let me know if you find one! @andredewaard

Answer (score 0):

You have to be sure that you are importing the following header in `Bridging-Header` file
`#import <RNCAsyncStorage/RNCAsyncStorage.h>`